# Firebase3 listen for change event and get the old data value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On Firebase3 I am looking for a way to get to old value from an item in a firebasearray. Is there any way to do it or can we override the child_changed event? The solution should be for firebase 3 javascript SDK.

```js
var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('post-comments/' + postId);

commentsRef.on('child_changed', function(data) {
  // data variable holds new data. I want the old one before the update happened!
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the old value with an event. If you need that, you'll have to track it yourself.

```
var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('post-comments/' + postId);
var oldValue;

commentsRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
    // TODO: compare data.val() with oldValue
    ...
    oldValue = snapshot.val();
});
```

Comment: but snapshot.val() would hold reference to the new one.

Comment: Yes. So next time the child changes, you'll have the old value.

Comment: ok, i see, thank you a lot but thats not the solution i am looking for. my problem is that application X is making the changes and application Y has to track them. I dont want to hold a copy of the whole data to track the changes. I have seen in the docs that it is possible to override firebase methods. Is there anyway to override the child_changed event so that it  returns me the old value insted of the new or can we construct in anyway new event listeners with custom behaviour?

Comment: As I said at the start of my answer: There is no way to get the old value with an event.